# Problem to stop lightdm

Tags: nvidia, lightdm

I'm trying to stop LightDM, but I receive the following error message (translated from German):

```
root@robert-desktop:/home/robert/Downloads# stop lightdm
stop: Connection to Upstart not possible: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
```

---

What can i do to stop lightdm to Install Nvidia driver?

Thx

Comment: are you using ubuntu 15.04 ?

Comment: service lightdm stop

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install additional drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers)

Answer (score 3):

It is not a good idea to install Nvidia drivers from .run files, downloaded from Nvidia site. This way they will not be registered properly by dkms and you will get black screen after first kernel update.

Good way to install the driver is to run:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Or go to System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers and install driver from there.

But if you are sure, that you need to do it this way, then here is the command:

```
sudo stop lightdm
```